# render normal map, diffuse color and height map

Tags: texture-baking, render-passes

I would like to make all the render needed to create a shader I can apply to a plane and get the same result as my composition with plenty of mesh.

here are all the meshes view from the side:
 [image]

I have already set up an orthographic camera above the fishes and made a first render but this render has got shadows:[image]

I need to render the normal of the fishes view by the camera,
the color of the fishes (without shadows), 
the ambiant occlusion,
a height map to serve as a displacement map on the plane I will finally apply the shader

Is it possible to select the type of render like in the baking menu or is it possible to bake what the camera sees on a plane ?

Comment: In 2.8 try Workbench rendering with matcaps, for normal map and height map, that should give a result.